# data is generated in database even if we perform preview data option in spoon

Tags: kettle

can some one suggest me best idea to overcome this situation. Iam using kettle 4.1.0 community version, here when i want to preview the data in spoon for the transformation table output, then when i click on preview data option, the data is being generated in database directly even if we are not performing Run transformation option.. how can i overcome this problem..

regards
kiran kumar.g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats just how it works.  Perhaps the name "preview" is badly named.

Couple of ways around it.  Preview the step before the table output, and disable the hop so no data goes to table output.  If the table output step is collecting several inputs, then put a "dummy" step and make that do the collecting, and then preview that.

or change your db to use a local db (via properties or jndi or even a different connection on the step) then you wont care if the db is generated.